# Debian packages naming, documentation is self-contradicting

Tags: debian, conventions

Debian policy manual (released on 2019-10-03) [clearly states](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#source) that
"Package names (both source and binary, see Package) **must consist only of lower case letters (a-z), digits (0-9), plus (+) and minus (-) signs, and periods (.)."**

At the same time, this [slightly older FAQ](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkg_basics#s-pkgname) (version 9.0, 17 November 2018) uses underscores in the examples.

Moreover, the repository itself contains many packages with underscores in names.

So, are there any strict rules, or, at least, a rule of thumb for naming?

Comment: Packages with underscore in their name? Like which one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The restrictions apply to package names (both source and binary), but the binary package *filenames* do contain underscores; these are used as separators. The Policy section you’re referring to described the former, the FAQ entry describes the latter. For example, [`0ad-data-common_0.0.17-1_all.deb`](http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/0/0ad-data/) is a valid binary package file name; it contains package `0ad-data-common`, in version 0.0.17-1, for the “all” architecture.

You won’t find incorrectly-named packages in the Debian repositories: invalid files are rejected before they can enter the archives.

Answer (score 0):

The naming is the one being stated in the policy. If you find a package that does not meet the policy, please file a bug report.